# PHP OOP Interface Code

Tags: php, class, interface

I am trying to do interface. I have create an interface and then I take two classes. Outside of those classes I am trying to declare a function which will access the common method that is in two classes with the help of interface. I am unable to access the method in the function. Could you please help?

My Code is as below:

```
 <?php 
interface shape{
function area();
}


class circle implements shape {
const pI=3.1416;
protected $rad;
public function __construct($a){
$this->rad=$a;
}
public function area(){
    return "The area of Circle is: <br />";
    return circle::pI*($this->rad^2)."<br />";
}
}


class rectangle implements shape{
        protected $length;
        protected $width;

    public function __construct($a,$b){
        $this->length=$a;
        $this->width=$b;

}
    public function area(){

        return "The area of Rectangle is: <br />";
        return $this->length*$this->width."<br />";
}
}

function price1(shape $price1){
    return "The Price of the area of rectangle is: <br />";
    return $price1->area()*1400;
}
function price2(shape $price2){
    return "The Price of the area of circle is: <br />";
    return $price2->area()*2600;
}

$obj1=new rectangle(7,12);
//$obj1->area();
echo price1($obj1);

$obj2=new circle(10);
//$obj2->area();
echo price2($obj2);


?>
```

I know there are many ways of solving this problem and I already solved it implementing the price function inside the class. But can I not follow these pattern? Is it wrong?

Comment: `$price2::area()` should be `$price2->area()`.

Comment: `public $length; public $wide;` defeats the purpose of encapsulation. Make them `protected` or even `private` and don't access them from outside the class.

Comment: `echo $this->length*$this->wide;` -- there is not the correct place for `echo` here (and it makes the top-level code fail). Make it `return $this->length * $this->wide;`

Comment: I have updated accordingly but it displays emply result for the price function.

Comment: Because the `area()` function should compute and return a value, not display it. If it displays it then you cannot use it in `price1()` and `price2()`.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question section. Could you please check and advise me where am I doing wrong and how? It would be a great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) causes the function to end its execution immediately. The second `return` in function `area()` is never executed. As a general rule, try to keep the computation and display separate. For the posted code, keep the output (`echo()`) in the main program, outside any function. Let the functions compute and `return` values. Read more about [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).